# is this a good setup for public/keys logins?

Tags: linux, openssl, openssh

I'm creating public/private keys to access to my VPS. I would like to understand how to organize better this kind of job.
At the moment I have a local user named **dail** and three users in the VPS woth their home like:

```
user1 -> /home/vhosts/user1
user2 -> /home/vhosts/user2
user3 -> /home/vhosts/user3
```

OK, now my goal is to connect from my PC to the VPS with public/private keys avoiding password logins.

I have generated three pairs of keys in my PC and then uploaded the public keys in the three home of the VPS users.
I have the private keys in `/home/dail/.ssh/` named like: user1.private user2.private user3.private and the publis are in:

```
/home/vhosts/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys (user1.pub)
/home/vhosts/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys (user2.pub)
/home/vhosts/user3/.ssh/authorized_keys (user3.pub)
```

I tested all the things and all works correctly but i woul dlike to understand if this is a good setup OR do i have to do the opposite?
I mean create the keys on the VPS and save the .pub keys in my pc... ?
Another thing is, in my local pc can I not create a directory with all the private keys avoiding to save them in the .ssh of the local user that has nothing to do with server users ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the keys on your local PC and upload the .pub Keyfile to your server's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is the right way.

Comment: ok perfect but where do i have to keep the private keys? why does it create them in my local user that has nothign to do with the users in the remove vps ?

Comment: I would create one public/private keypair on the local computer and place the public key at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for each user i want to login. In your case all three .ssh/authorized_keys would be the same. So you can login with ssh user1@server or user2@server without using a password